# I want to display .swf file on html page but it is not displaying on webpage

Tags: html, apache-flex, flash, wicket

I am newer with flex or .swf .
 i am trying to embed a .swf file but it does not displaying
please tell me what would i do so that it will display
please tell me if my .swf in bin folder then how does i display on page??

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<wicket:extend>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Chart.....</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form wicket:id="ChartForm">
<table border="0" align="center" bgcolor=#488AC7 bordercolor="#25383C" width="93%">
                <tr align="center">
                    <td colspan="2" align="right"><font size="2" color="#151B8D"><b><wicket:message key="SEARCHBYSYMBOL"></wicket:message></b></font></td>
                    <td colspan="4" align="left" > 
                    <input name="symbol" id="symbol" type="text" value="" size="25" wicket:id="txtSymbol"   />
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                        <input type="submit" wicket:id="btnSymbolsubmit" style=" width : 53px;" value="submit">

                    </td>
                    <td style=" width : 107px;" align="right"><font size="2" color="#151B8D"><b><wicket:message key="EXPIRYDATE"></wicket:message>  </b></font></td>
                    <td colspan="2"  align="left">
                    <select wicket:id="dDCExpiryDate" style=" width : 98px;"></select>&nbsp;
                    <input type="submit" wicket:id="btnGetCalData" value="OK">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div style="position: relative;height: 500; overflow:hidden; width : 700;" align="center"> 
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
        id="candlestickAndOHLC" width="860" height="400"
        codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
        <param name="movie" value="candlestickAndOHLC.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
        <embed src="bin\CandleStick.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff"
            width="860" height="400" name="candlestickAndOHLC" align="middle"
            play="true"
            loop="false"
            allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
            type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
            pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
        </embed>
</object>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</wicket:extend>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you have a look at *SWFObject* which is an easy-to-use and standards-friendly method to embed Flash content, which utilizes one small JavaScript file.

You can read the documentation and download it from [here](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)